# trying to understand recursive run of generators

Tags: python, generator, yield

I'm trying to figure out how to plot the run of this code onto a recursion tree, because im not quite sure how it operates, even when I'm debugging.
what each yield is doing and why do I need them both?

Ive tried creating a somewhat tree that connects each run to its next recursively but I dont know what follows yield.data where the head is 'c'

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


def get_reverse_iterator(head):
    if head.next:
        for datum in get_reverse_iterator(head.next):
            yield datum
    yield head.data


lst = Node('a', Node('b', Node('c')))
for x in get_reverse_iterator(lst):
    print(x)
```

the result should be:
c
b
a

Comment: The first loop with yield can be written shortly by `yield from get_reverse_iterator(head.next)`.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you expect this to work? I don't quite understand where your understanding breaks down.

Comment: It works fine for me, what is your doubt? How it expands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand how it works you need to understand the basic idea of recursion. Let's suppose that we are not dealing with a generators; we just wish to print all the nodes of a list in reverse given the head node. We call the function **print_reverse** passing the node as the argument. If the node's **next** field is empty we just print the field's **data** value. But if **next** is not empty, it is pointing to a node that must be printed before the current node is printed. So we recursively call **print_reverse** again to first print that node. When **print_reverse** returns we can now print the current node. Of course, when we call **print_reverse** recursively to print the next node, it may discover that there is yet another node that it points to which must first be printed and we will be calling **print_reverse** recursively yet again. So we have:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


def print_reverse(head):
    if head.next:
        print_reverse(head.next)
    print(head.data)


lst = Node('a', Node('b', Node('c')))
print_reverse(lst)
```

The above code must be understood before the generator problem can be understood. Instead of creating a function **print_reverse** that prints the node's **data** field, we wish instead to create a generator function that *yields* the value. So, it makes sense to rename the function and to replace the print function with a `yield` statement and the recursive call with a `yield from` statement:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


def get_reverse_iterator(head):
    if head.next:
        #print_reverse(head.next)
        yield from get_reverse_iterator(head.next)
    #print(head.data)
    yield head.data

lst = Node('a', Node('b', Node('c')))
```

Now we can use the generator as in:

```
for x in get_reverse_iterator(lst):
    print(x)
```

or:

```
l = [x in get_reverse_iterator(lst)]
```

But an alternative to using recursion that avoids creating multiple generator objects, would be:

```
def get_reverse_iterator(head):
    stack = []
    while head.next:
        stack.append(head)
        head = head.next
    yield head.data
    while len(stack):
        head = stack.pop()
        yield head.data
```

Comment: that's a great comparison, thank you. a small question - why do I need two yields using a generator, whereas when we were not using generators all that was needed is to print the data?

Comment: There is one generator function, `get_reverse_iterator`. When we were just printing we had one print statement and **one recursive call back to "our self**".  In the generator case, the call to the print function becomes a **yield statement** and the recursive call to our self becomes a **yield from** "our self".

Comment: You "accepted the other answer and said, "brilliant." Presumably you understood the explanation. As mentioned in a previous comment, the **yield from** is an alternate, simplified syntax for your original `for datum in get_reverse_iterator(head.next): yield datum`. I think it parallels the recursive call I had in the printing example more closely besides being a simpler syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call the method as a generator (e.g. `for x in get_reverse_iterator()`), python starts executing that method line by line. Whenever it hits a `yield`, it stops cold and returns that. When it gets asked for a `next()` value in the next iteration of the `for` loop, it continues to execute.

This looks like a fairly straightforward linked-list-traversal idiom, where each element of the list contains data that is itself a list (or some other iterable value, like a string):

```
list[0].data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list[1].data = [5, 6, 7, 8]
...
list[9].data = [37, 38, 39, 40]
```

So what the code is doing *here* is printing those sub-lists from the back of the main list to the front of the main list. The output should look something like this:

```
37 38 39 40 33 34 35 36 ... 5 6 7 8 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

which becomes evident when you look at how the code executes. I'll rewrite it in words:

```
func get_reverse_iterator(head) {
    if head isn't the last element of the list, then
        call this function on the next element of the list (head.next)
        for every element in the return value of that,
            yield that element
    yield this element's data
```

The 'base case' is the last element of the list, which doesn't have a `.next`. So its `data`, which is iterable, gets returned to the second-to-last element. The second-to-last element yields every element of that data in turn, and then returns its own data to the third-to-last element. The third-to-last element yields every element of that data in turn, and so on, until finally you get to the first element of the list. Every single `yield` statement thus far has passed one element up the chain, recursively, and so that inner `for` loop for the first element has yielded 36 values so far. Finally, all the later elements in the list are done passing values through, and so the first element gets to the last statement of the function and yields its own data.

But there's nothing left to catch that yielded data and parse it by individual element, so it gets printed as the `list` it was in the first place. Or, at least, that is for my example presented above.

---

In your case, it's more straightforward, because when you iterate over a `string` each item is still a `string`. But it's the same thing on a smaller scale:

1. `get_reverse_iterator()` is called on the root node of `lst`
2. The root node (I'll call it `NodeA`) has a `.next`
3. `get_reverse_iterator()` is called on the next node, which I'll call `NodeB`
4. `NodeB` has a `.next`
5. `get_reverse_iterator()` is called on the next node, which I'll call `NodeC`
6. `NodeC` does not have a `.next`
7. `get_reverse_iterator(NodeC)` skips the `for` loop and yields `NodeC.data`, which is 'c'`
8. `get_reverse_iterator(NodeB)` catches `'c'` inside the `for` loop and yields it
9. `get_reverse_iterator(NodeA)` catches `'c'` inside the `for` loop and yields it
10. `'c'` gets assigned to `x`, and it gets printed.
11. The next iteration of the outer loop happens, and execution returns to `get_reverse_iterator(NodeB)`
12. The `for` loop ends, because `get_reverse_iterator(NodeC)` has stopped yielding things
13. `get_reverse_iterator(NodeB)` ends the `for` loop, exits the `if` block, and finally yields `NodeB.data`, which is `'b'`
14. `get_reverse_iterator(NodeA)` catches `'b'` inside the `for` loop and yields it
15. `'b'` gets assigned to `x`, and it gets printed.
16. The next iteration of the outer loop happens, and execution returns to `get_reverse_iterator(NodeA)`
17. The `for` loop ends, because `get_reverse_iterator(NodeC)` has stopped yielding things
18. `get_reverse_iterator(NodeA)` ends the `for` loop, exits the `if` block, and finally yields `NodeA.data`, which is `'a'`
19. `'a'` gets assigned to `x`, and it gets printed
20. The outer `for` loop finishes, as `get_reverse_iterator(NodeA)` has stopped yielding things.

Comment: brilliant! that sums up all I needed!. one small thing - in step 12/13 can you explain why the for loop ends and exits the if block?

Comment: A `for` loop in python continues until there ceases to be a "next element". In step 12, what's happening is `get_reverse_iterator(NodeB)` asks for the next value of `get_reverse_iterator(NodeC)`. But since `get_reverse_iterator(NodeC)` has completely finished its execution, there's no next value to yield, and so `get_reverse_iterator(NodeB)` decides the `for` loop is over and moves on. Because that's the only thing in the `if` block, it exits the `if` block in the process - the next line of code to be executed is the last one in the function.